# 2D arrays using NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, multidimensional-array, nsmutablearray

I need to create a mutable two-dimensional array in Objective-C.

For example I have:

```
NSMutableArray *sections;
NSMutableArray *rows;
```

Each item in `sections` consists of an array `rows`. `rows` is an array that contains objects.

And I want to do something like this:

```
[ sections[i] addObject: objectToAdd]; //I want to add a new row
```

In order have something like this:
section 0, rows: obj1, obj2, obj3
section 1, rows: obj4, obj5, obj6, obj 7...

Is there a way to do that in Objective-C?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

First, you must allocate and initialize your objects before use, something like: `NSMutableArray * sections = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:10];` For the rows, you need one object for each, not a single `NSMutableArray * rows;`

Second, depending on whether you're using Xcode 4.4+ (which introduced subscripting, a.k.a `section[i]` & `section[i] = …`) you may have to use `[sections objectAtIndex:i]` for reading and `[section replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject: objectToAdd]` for writing.

Third, an array cannot have holes, i.e., obj1, nil, obj2. You must provide actual object to every index. If you do need to put nothing, you can use [`NSNull`](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNull_Class/Reference/Reference.html) object.

Moreover, don't forget that you can also store Objective-C objects in plain C arrays:

```
id table[lnum][rnum];
table[i][j] = myObj;
```

Comment: Excellent suggest to use plain C arrays, especially where array dimensions are known ahead of time.

Comment: Wish I could answer++ again for the NSNull object filling the holes. I just realized the significance.

Comment: You can now use subscript indexing

Comment: And you no longer can store objects in C arrays under ARC.

Comment: @iMartin: That's not correct. Just did it. No warnings, crashes whatsoever. You need `__unsafe_unretained` for **storing Objective-C objects** in **structs** though. Or else clang will throw an error.

Comment: @Regexident You are right. But it is _unsafe_, because the object is _unretained_ and you need to do additional **bridging**.

Comment: @iMartin: Sure, everything in C is unsafe. No exception here. And neither should one expect one, imho. It's just following the new rules of ARC. For temporary in-scope storage it's still totally okay. Everything else will need either `__bridge_…` or `CFRetain`/`CFRelease`, which is fine to me. Going bare-metal should require additional effort, and as such make you rethink your overall design.

Answer (score 17):

If you want to do this using arrays, you can intialize your `sections` array, then add a rows array as follows:

```
NSMutableArray *sections = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *rows = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
//Add row objects here

//Add your rows array to the sections array
[sections addObject:rows];
```

If you want to add this rows object at a certain index, use the following:

```
//Insert your rows array at index i
[sections insertObject:rows atIndex:i];
```

You can then modify this rows array by retrieving the array:

```
//Retrieve pointer to rows array at index i
NSMutableArray *rows = [sections objectAtIndex:i]
//modify rows array here
```

You could always create your own class called `Section`, which has an `NSMutableArray` member called `rows`; then you store your rows inside this array, and store the `Section` objects in an array:

```
@interface Section : NSObject {
    NSMutableArray *rows;
}
```

Then you simply create `Section` items, and you can create methods inside your class to add/remove row items. Then you package all the `Sections` items up inside another array:

```
Section *aSection = [[Section alloc] init];
//add any rows to your Section instance here

NSMutableArray *sections = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[sections addObject:aSection];
```

This becomes more useful if you want to add more properties for each `Section` instance.

Answer (score 9):

The language has no support for multi-dimensional object-oriented arrays, but you can make a class that does it using an NSMutableArray full of NSMutableArrays, like the following.  I haven't tried compiling this or anything, I just typed it in.

```
@interface SectionArray : NSObject {
  NSMutableArray *sections;
}
- initWithSections:(NSUInteger)s rows:(NSUInteger)r;
+ sectionArrayWithSections:(NSUInteger)s rows:(NSUInteger)r;
- objectInSection:(NSUInteger)s row:(NSUInteger)r;
- (void)setObject:o inSection:(NSUInteger)s row:(NSUInteger)r;
@end
@implementation SectionArray
- initWithSections:(NSUInteger)s rows:(NSUInteger)r {
  if ((self = [self init])) {
    sections = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:s];
    NSUInteger i;
    for (i=0; i<s; i++) {
      NSMutableArray *a = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:r];
      for (j=0; j<r; j++) {
        [a setObject:[NSNull null] atIndex:j];
      }
      [sections addObject:a];
    }
  }
  return self;
}
+ sectionArrayWithSections:(NSUInteger)s rows:(NSUInteger)r {
  return [[[self alloc] initWithSections:s rows:r] autorelease];
}
- objectInSection:(NSUInteger)s row:(NSUInteger)r {
  return [[sections objectAtIndex:s] objectAtIndex:r];
}
- (void)setObject:o inSection:(NSUInteger)s row:(NSUInteger)r {
  [[sections objectAtIndex:s] replaceObjectAtIndex:r withObject:0];
}
@end
```

You'd use it like this:

```
SectionArray *a = [SectionArray arrayWithSections:10 rows:5];
[a setObject:@"something" inSection:4 row:3];
id sameOldSomething = [s objectInSection:4 row:3];
```

Answer (score 6):

what the hell.  As long as we're reviving this question, here's something for the age of literal collection syntax and visual format interpretation!

In case anyone is wondering, this works:

```
NSMutableArray *multi = [@[ [@[] mutableCopy] , [@[] mutableCopy] ] mutableCopy];
multi[1][0] = @"Hi ";
multi[1][1] = @"There ";
multi[0][0] = @"Oh ";
multi[0][1] = @"James!";        
NSLog(@"%@%@%@%@", multi[0][0], multi[1][0], multi[1][1], multi[0][1]);
```

Result: "Oh Hi There James!"

Of course, there is the problem of trying something like `multi[3][5] = @"?"` and getting an invalid index exception, so I wrote a category for NSMutableArray.

```
@interface NSMutableArray (NullInit)
+(NSMutableArray *)mutableNullArrayWithSize:(NSUInteger)size;
+(NSMutableArray *)mutableNullArraysWithVisualFormat:(NSString *)string;
@end

@implementation NSMutableArray (NullInit)

+(NSMutableArray *)mutableNullArrayWithSize:(NSUInteger)size
{
    NSMutableArray *returnArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        [returnArray addObject:[NSNull null]];
    }
    return returnArray;
}

+(NSMutableArray *)mutableNullArraysWithVisualFormat:(NSString *)string
{
    NSMutableArray *returnArray = nil;
    NSRange bitRange;
    if ((bitRange = [string rangeOfString:@"^\\[\\d+]" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch]).location != NSNotFound) {
        NSUInteger size = [[string substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, bitRange.length - 2)] integerValue];
        if (string.length == bitRange.length) {
            returnArray = [self mutableNullArrayWithSize:size];
        } else {
            returnArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:size];
            NSString *nextLevel = [string substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(bitRange.length, string.length - bitRange.length)];
            NSMutableArray *subArray;
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                subArray = [self mutableNullArraysWithVisualFormat:nextLevel];
                if (subArray) {
                    [returnArray addObject:subArray];
                } else {
                    return nil;
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        return nil;
    }
    return returnArray;
}

@end
```

As you can see, we have a convenience method for making an array full of `NSNull` so that you can set indices with wild abandon.

Secondly, there's a recursive method that parses a string with a visual format like: `[3][12]` (3 x 12 array).  If your string is invalid in some way the method will return `nil`, but if it's valid you get a whole multidimensional array of the sizes you specify.

Here are some examples:

```
NSMutableArray *shrub = [NSMutableArray mutableNullArrayWithSize:5];
NSMutableArray *tree = [NSMutableArray mutableNullArraysWithVisualFormat:@"[3][12]"]; // 2-Dimensional Array
NSMutableArray *threeDeeTree = [NSMutableArray mutableNullArraysWithVisualFormat:@"[3][5][6]"]; // 3-Dimensional Array
NSMutableArray *stuntedTree = [NSMutableArray mutableNullArraysWithVisualFormat:@"[6][4][k]"]; // Returns nil
```

You can pass as many dimensions as you like into the visual format method, and then access them with the literal syntax, like so:

```
NSMutableArray *deepTree = [NSMutableArray mutableNullArraysWithVisualFormat:@"[5][3][4][2][7]"];
deepTree[3][2][1][0][5] = @"Leaf";
NSLog(@"Look what's at 3.2.1.0.5: %@", deepTree[3][2][1][0][5]);
```

Anyway, did this more as an exercise than anything else; it's probably pretty efficient in the grand scheme of things...considering as how we're making multi-dimensional arrays of Objective-C object pointers.

Comment: For collection with holes I use `NSMutableDictionary`, where the key is set of indexes like this: `[dict setObject:o forKey: @[ @2, @5]]` This way you don't get `NSNull` everywhere

Comment: @iMartin Hm, what does that do when you call `setObject` with an array as the key?  Does it set the object as the value for each key in the array?  Also, I think you want to do `@(2)` to make it a number, I don't think it's valid without the parentheses.

Comment: It is valid without `()`. If you use array of numbers as a key, the object is asociated with the given index combination. Nothign else. It is just normal key.

Comment: @iMartin You're right, it is valid without `()`, my bad. I didn't know that you could use an array of numbers as a key, that's neat! Do you have a reference or article or sample code? I'd like to know more.

Comment: You can use any object as a key (that supports Copying) and when objects are equal, they return the same `-hash`, so this approach works correctly. The array doesn't need to be the same instance, but it must have the same logical content.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to Jack for his code , i worked on it a bit; i need a multidimensional nsmutablearray for strings in one of my project , it still has some things that need to be fixed but works strings only at the moment , i will post it here , i am open for suggestions please cause i am only just a beginner in objective c at the moment...

```
@interface SectionArray : NSObject {

  NSMutableArray *sections;    

}
- initWithSections:(NSUInteger)intSections:(NSUInteger)intRow;
+ sectionArrayWithSections:(NSUInteger)intSections:(NSUInteger)intRows;
- objectInSection:(NSUInteger)intSection:(NSUInteger)intRow;
- (void)setObject:(NSString *)object:(NSUInteger)intSection:(NSUInteger)intRow;
@end

@implementation SectionArray

- initWithSections:(NSUInteger)intSections:(NSUInteger)intRow {
    NSUInteger i;
    NSUInteger j;

    if ((self = [self init])) {
        sections = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:intSections];
        for (i=0; i < intSections; i++) {
            NSMutableArray *a = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:intRow];
            for (j=0; j < intRow; j++) {
                [a insertObject:[NSNull null] atIndex:j];
            }
            [sections addObject:a];
        }
    }
    return self;    
}
- (void)setObject:(NSString *)object:(NSUInteger)intSection:(NSUInteger)intRow {
    [[sections objectAtIndex:intSection] replaceObjectAtIndex:intRow withObject:object];
}
- objectInSection:(NSUInteger)intSection:(NSUInteger)intRow {
    return [[sections objectAtIndex:intSection] objectAtIndex:intRow];
}
+ sectionArrayWithSections:(NSUInteger)intSections:(NSUInteger)intRows {
    return [[self alloc] initWithSections:intSections:intRows] ;
}
@end
```

This is working fine !!!

i am currently using it like this

```
SectionArray *secA = [[SectionArray alloc] initWithSections:2:2];
[secA setObject:@"Object":0:0];
[secA setObject:@"ObjectTwo":0:1];
[secA setObject:@"ObjectThree":1:0];
[secA setObject:@"ObjectFour":1:1];

NSString *str = [secA objectInSection:1:1];

NSLog(@" object is = %@" , str);
```

Thanks again Jack !!

Answer (score 0):

FYI: Jack's code needs a bunch of work before it works. Among other issues, the autorelease can cause the data to get released before you access it and his usage calls the class method arrayWithSections:rows: when it is actually defined as sectionArrayWithSections:rows:

I may try to post actual working code later if I get a chance.

Answer (score 0):

Reviving an old thread, but I reworked Jack's code so 1. it compiles and 2. it is in the order of 2D c arrays [rows][columns] instead of [sections(columns)][rows] as he has it. Here you go!

TwoDArray.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface TwoDArray : NSObject

@property NSMutableArray *rows;

- initWithRows:(NSUInteger)rows columns:(NSUInteger)columns;
+ sectionArrayWithRows:(NSUInteger)rows columns:(NSUInteger)columns;
- objectInRow:(NSUInteger)row column:(NSUInteger)column;
- (void)setObject:(id)obj inRow:(NSUInteger)row column:(NSUInteger)column;

@end
```

TwoDArray.m:

```
#import "TwoDArray.h"

@implementation TwoDArray

- (id)initWithRows:(NSUInteger)rows columns:(NSUInteger)columns {
    if ((self = [self init])) {
        self.rows = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity: rows];
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            NSMutableArray *column = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:columns];
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
                [column setObject:[NSNull null] atIndexedSubscript:j];
            }
            [self.rows addObject:column];
        }
    }
    return self;
}
+ (id)sectionArrayWithRows:(NSUInteger)rows columns:(NSUInteger)columns {
    return [[self alloc] initWithRows:rows columns:columns];
}
- (id)objectInRow:(NSUInteger)row column:(NSUInteger)column {
    return [[self.rows objectAtIndex:row] objectAtIndex:column];
}
- (void)setObject:(id)obj inRow:(NSUInteger)row column:(NSUInteger)column {
    [[self.rows objectAtIndex:row] replaceObjectAtIndex:column withObject:obj];
}
@end
```

Comment: If you're going to revive this old thread, at least use modern things like the literal array syntax, some good links here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13482653/700471  I think you can even do something like `myArray[0][3]`, although I could be wrong.

Comment: @MattMc: Thanks for the link! I'm fairly inexperienced in this, just thought I'd share what worked for me. Will definitely check that out though.

Comment: Sure thing :)  I took my own suggestion and threw together a method that incorporates the literal syntax and so on, so you can get an idea; it's below.

Answer (score -1):

This is what I did in order to initialize array of arrays.

```
NSMutableArray *arrayOfArrays = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:CONST];

for (int i=0; i<=CONST; i++) {
    [arrayOfArrays addObject:[NSMutableArray array]];
}
```

Then later in a code I could simply:

```
[[arrayOfArrays objectAtIndex:0] addObject:myObject];
```

Comment: 1st: you are not adding anything new and valuable to this thread. 2nd: if we are talking of 2-dimensional arrays by using NSArrays, it must be added how to deal with empty entries.