# Deleting elements of an NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I've been trying to fix a bug for really long and I could do with some suggestions. I have two NSMutableArrays `tem` and `list`. `list` is an arrayWithArrays, so every time I load data onto `tem` after finishing I say `[list addObject: tem];` My code is such that, before adding a fresh set of data to `tem`, I delete all it's elements and begin adding elements again. However deleting the elements from `tem` results in them being deleted from `list` as well. What can I do to avoid it being deleted from `list`?

Comment: I would be really use full if you can post code.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean by "'list' is an arrayWithArrays" -- if it's meant to be a standard method, it's wrong -- so you ought to clarify this. But answering what I *think* is your question:

`addObject` adds the object itself, ie just a pointer to your array `tem`. Both pointers still refer to the same NSArray instance, so anything you do via one will also be seen via the other. If this confuses you, you should [read up on pointers](http://boredzo.org/pointers/).

If you actually want the objects in `list` to be grouped inside an internal array like `tem`, you should create a new `tem` array each time:

```
[list addObject:tem];
tem = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:1];
// new stuff added to tem will not appear in the array inside list
```

(Be careful with object ownership here -- this example uses a convenience method that will autorelease `tem`, but you may need to `retain` and `release` appropriately.)

If, on the other hand, you want the objects *inside* `tem` to be added into `list`, use `addObjectsFromArray`:

```
[list addObjectsFromArray:tem];
// objects in list will not be affected by subsequent changes to tem
[tem removeAllObjects];
```

Comment: Thank you,that was very useful. What I meant  was that I want the NSMutableArray list to be a 2D array, that is make use of the '[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:myArray]' type. So every time I add a new array to list, I'd like it to be stored as if it's a new row like in a 2D array. How will I be able to do that?

Comment: @Label `arrayWithArray` doesn't do that. It just fills the new array with the contents of the one you pass in. There is no 2D `NSMutableArray` type, it's up to you to make use of your arrays in a 2D fashion. The answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/724772/2d-arrays-in-objective-c) might help.