# 2D array in Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I want to create a global array, I was looking in to NSMutableArray because you can index it. I need to be able to call specific lines of the array and display via a label the 1st part of the array and compare users input with the second part.

Example is: User sees, press "x" (this is the first part of the array) and if the click one button it will compare that button id to the second part of the array.

Im not familiar with arrays in objective C, links or code snips will help!

Comment: it dupicates http://stackoverflow.com/questions/724772/2d-arrays-in-objective-c

Comment: @Gargo correct, it is a duplicate, but you should not flag because of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sound like a bit like you have a question answer format...

What you could do is have an `NSArray` of Question the objects that may look something like

```
@interface PSQuestion : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy)   NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger answer;

@end

@implementation PSQuestion

@synthesize title  = _title;
@synthesize answer = _answer;

@end
```

Nw you can have an indexed array of objects that contain both components you require

```
// Configure questions
PSQuestion *question1 = [[PSQuestion alloc] init];
question1.title  = @"Click X";
question1.answer = 2;
```

Comment: is there a way, i can make the question number a int? so like PSQuestion *question[num] I need to have a big data set and randomize the question. and How can I make it global?

Answer (score 0):

> I need to be able to call specific lines of the array and display via
>   a label the 1st part of the array and compare users input with the
>   second part.

No problem!  NSArray or it's mutable counterpart can store strings just as easily as any other object.  It's as simple as `[mymutablearray addObject:@"mystring"];.`

> User sees, press "x" (this is the first part of the array) and if the
>   click one button it will compare that button id to the second part of
>   the array.

To compare two arrays use `[_array1 isEqualToArray:array2];`, to compare strings within an array to a button label, use

`[[array1 objectAtIndex:0]isEqualToString:myButton.titleLabel.text];`

Comment: for comparing, I need to have like x and y linked somehow, thats why I dont want to have two different arrays to compare

Comment: An NSDictionary then?  You have an object and a key.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you only need a one dimensional array of objects that have two elements.  Define a class that has the two parts of which you speak, and then make an NSMutableArray full of instances of that class.