# Store latitude and longitude in NSMutableArray Xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

How to store multiple points (latitude and longitude) in `NSMutableArray`?

Comment: Please search, before posting questions. Here is a way to create 2D arrays http://stackoverflow.com/questions/724772/2d-arrays-in-objective-c

Comment: @SharonNathaniel this isn't a question about 2D arrays. Latitude and longitude are not integers, they could not be used as indicies to an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//NSMutable array to store values
NSMutableArray *array =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];    
//some lat and long values
NSDictionary *latLongDict = @{@"lat" : @(18.25689), @"long":@(48.25689)};

//add the objects to the array
[array addObject:latLongDict];
```

Comment: NSNumber would be a better fit if you were to do this. But in my view it doesn't make sense to store the pair as separate entities in the array.

Answer (score 6):

You've got a few options:

- Create your own object with latitude and longitude properties and store this
- Use the [CLLocationCoordinate2D](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocationDataTypesRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010238-CH2-SW15) struct and wrap it in an [NSValue](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsvalue_Class/Reference/Reference.html) object
- Use the [CLLocation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html) object

I'd recommend the latter, as you might find that you'll need the extra functionality on CLLocation later.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the data inside a dictionary object:

```
NSMutableArray *locationArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

//some lat and long values
CGFloat latitude = 18.25689;
CGFloat longitude = 48.25689;

NSDictionary *locationDict = @{ @"latitude" : [NSNumber numberWithFloat:latitude], @"longitude" : [NSNumber numberWithFloat:longitude] };

[locationArray addObject:locationDict];
```

and access them by:

```
NSUInteger anIndex = 0;
NSDictionary *locDict = [locationArray objectAtIndex:anIndex];
NSNumber *latitudeNumber = (NSNumber *)[locDict objectForKey:@"latitude"];
NSNumber *longitudeNumber = (NSNumber *)[locDict objectForKey:@"longitude"];
```

Answer (score -1):

Using Mapkit framework you can find the current location along with near by location with their latitude & longitude

```
 CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
 location = [mMapView.userLocation coordinate];

 if(iLat && iLng) 
 {

    location.latitude = [iLat floatValue];
    location.longitude = [iLng floatValue];
 }
```

Store value on array

```
NSMutableArray *a= [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:location.latitude,location.longitude, nil];
```

Comment: Latitude and longitude are doubles, not objects.

Comment: And your first example makes no sense. What is this?