# Weird objective-c syntax - square brackets and @ sign

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, syntax

I'm using GHSidebarNav in one of my projects and I came across this code allocating an array of objects. I just have no idea what its doing. Is it just an array? What is this weird `@[...]` syntax? I have not seen that before:

```
NSArray *controllers = @[
    @[
        [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[GHRootViewController alloc] initWithTitle:@"Profile" withRevealBlock:revealBlock]]
    ],
    @[
        [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[GHRootViewController alloc] initWithTitle:@"News Feed" withRevealBlock:revealBlock]],
        [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[GHMessagesViewController alloc] initWithTitle:@"Messages" withRevealBlock:revealBlock]],
        [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[GHRootViewController alloc] initWithTitle:@"Nearby" withRevealBlock:revealBlock]],
        [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[GHRootViewController alloc] initWithTitle:@"Events" withRevealBlock:revealBlock]],
        [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[GHRootViewController alloc] initWithTitle:@"Friends" withRevealBlock:revealBlock]]
    ]
];
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25749/what-does-the-symbol-represent-in-objective-c

Comment: @RobertHarvey Your link makes no mention of the new array literal syntax.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are array literals, a type of container literal, [available](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/ObjCAvailabilityIndex/_index.html) in Xcode 4.4 and later.

See:

- "Literal syntax" section of the [discussion of arrays in the Programming with Objective C](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/FoundationTypesandCollections/FoundationTypesandCollections.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH7-SW13)
- [Objective-C Literals](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html) discussion at the LLVM site
- WWDC 2012 [Modern Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=405), about 19-20 minutes into it
- WWDC 2012 [Migrating to Modern Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=413)

Comment: Ah yes. I did find that slide with the `@[` array syntax on it. Thanks for the links

Answer (score 3):

That's a new objective C literal that is declaring a multi dimensional array.

It's replacing `[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:...], [NSArray arrayWithObjects:..]]];`